# circular importing in python

Tags: python, python-import, circular-dependency

Two files, file1.py, file2.py. Can someone please explain why line 1.8 will print spam == 1 and not spam == 2 ? I've read all python circular import posts but I still don't understand this. Also, I don't understand why file1 is interpreted again from scratch when imported from file2. I was under the impression modules are not loaded again once they've been imported once.

```
# file1.py
print('1.1: initializing spam to 0')
spam = 0
spam += 1
print('1.4: spam == {}'.format(spam))
print('1.5: importing file2')
import file2
print('1.7: imported file2')
print('1.8: spam == {}'.format(spam))  # why 1 and not 2?
print('FILE 1 PARSED')  # why is this executed twice?

# file2.py
print('\t\t\t2.1: importing file1')
import file1
print('\t\t\t2.3: imported file1, file1.spam == {}'.format(file1.spam))
file1.spam += 1
import file1
print('\t\t\t2.6: print from file2: file1.spam == {}'.format(file1.spam))
print('\t\t\tFILE 2 PARSED')
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
1.1: initializing spam to 0
1.4: spam == 1
1.5: importing file2
            2.1: importing file1
1.1: initializing spam to 0
1.4: spam == 1
1.5: importing file2
1.7: imported file2
1.8: spam == 1
FILE 1 PARSED
            2.3: imported file1, file1.spam == 1
            2.6: print from file2: file1.spam == 2
            FILE 2 PARSED
1.7: imported file2
1.8: spam == 1
FILE 1 PARSED
```

PS. I appreciate circular imports are to be avoided, but I need to understand the logic.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python -- I think there's enough information there to answer your question.

Comment: you're right in that it does answer the question, but the answer from @6502 got directly imprinted on my brain, which was not the case with the other post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python import more or less goes as

1. look if there's a module with that name already, if so return it immediately
2. the module has not been imported, so create the module object and put it in the registry immediately, then load the source and execute it

What happens if you execute `file1` is that the execution start as a main program then

1. `file1` code imports `file2`: since it was not present so the module object is created and execution of `file2` begins
2. `file2` code imports `file1`: since `file1` was not present **as a module** then a module object is created and execution of `file1` begins (as a module!)
3. `file1` code (as a module) imports `file2`: the module is already present so the partially constructed `file2` module object is returned immediately
4. `file1` as a module completes execution and `file2` resumes after import
5. `file2` module completes execution and `file1` **as main program** resumes after import
6. the program completes

In other words there will be two instances of `spam`: one inside the "main program" file1.py and one inside the **module** `file1`.

Consider this simplified test case:

```
# p1.py
import p2, sys
p1d = {}
print id(p1d), id(sys.modules['p1'].p1d)

# p2.py
import p1
print "HERE"
```

running `p1.py` you will get as output something like

```
18465168 18465168
HERE
17940640 18465168
```

the first two numbers are equal because the `print` is executed from the `p1` **module** while the second two numbers are different because `print` is executed from `p1` **main program**, that is a different instance.

PS: if you write intentionally code that does this (i.e. a main that indirectly import another instance of itself as a module) you should be put in jail :-)

Comment: excellent answer, completely understood now! thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

When `file1.py` is run as the main script, it is not the `file1` module. It is the `__main__` module. Pretend it's a completely separate file that happens to look exactly like the `file1` module, because that's how Python treats it.

Python runs `file1.py` as `__main__`, which imports `file2`, which imports `file1`. Since the `__main__` module is not considered the same as the `file1` module, `file1.py` runs again.

When `file1` imports `file2`, since `file2` is already being imported, `file1` fetches the half-constructed `file2` module object and keeps going. It does not give `file2` a chance to increase `file1.spam`. This is why the first instance of line 1.8 prints 1.

When execution gets back to `file2`, it increases `file1.spam`, so line 2.6 prints 2. However, `__main__.spam` is still 1. This is why when execution gets back to `__main__`, the second instance of line 1.8 also prints 1.